# Laravel 6.0 migration - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, mariadb, laravel-6

I'm trying to create the migrations with laravel and i get this error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = tutories and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /Users/ivanortega/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/codi/UVIC/Tutories/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /Users/ivanortega/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/codi/UVIC/Tutories/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:unix_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=tutories", "root", "", [])
      /Users/ivanortega/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/codi/UVIC/Tutories/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

I have tried to change the hostname, and the socket. Nothing works

This is my .env conf file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tutories
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SOCKET=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I check that the socket exists, and I also create a link to /tmp/mysql.sock. 
I change the php.ini file:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Program versions:

```
XAMPP: 7.3.9
PHP: 7.3.6
MariaDB: 10.0.34
MAC:MacOS Mojave v10.14.6
```

Comment: `composer dumpa` , `php artisan optimize:clear`, `php artisan config:cache` ?

Comment: @Vipertecpro Nothing, same error..

Comment: Remove all db and re migrate again `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Comment: @Vipertecpro nothing.. i think it's all about the new xapp vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fonund the solution, newest versions of xampp in macOS works with a virtual machine, so when I run the migrate it was taking the db on my computer, not in the local machine. 
Downloading the last version without the virtual machine works!

Answer (score 1):

here i have two solution

1. change in you .env file

   **`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`**

   to

   **`DB_HOST=localhost`**

   and then run following command to clear config file
   **php artisan config:clear**
2. second way to solved this issue is add following line in you .env file

   **`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`**

Comment: This one helped on mac. thanks
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

FOR Mac OS, try to add the following line in your .env

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```